# Include HTML template file in wp_mail

Tags: email, wp-mail, html-email

I'm using `wp_mail()` to send an HTML email. But there's quite a lot of HTML code in the email, so rather than including all the code in my `wp_mail()` function, is it possible to have the code in a separate template and just include this template in the function? Here is what I have:

```
<?php if ( isset( $_POST['submitted'] )) {
   add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));
   $emailTo = 'person@gmail.com' ;
   $subject = 'This is the subject';
   $body = get_template_part( 'includes/my_email_template' );
   $headers = 'From: My Name' . "\r\n";
   wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
}?>
```

I'd like to be able to put all of my HTML code in 'my_email_template' but when I try this, no email is sent. Am I including the template incorrectly? Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Syntax error: `$emailTo = person@gmail.com ;` try `$emailTo = 'person@gmail.com';`.

Comment: You're calling the template incorrectly - see [the codex for get_template_part](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part)

Comment: Thank you both. That syntax error was just poor copy/paste/adjust from me. I can confirm it's correct in my actual template.

Comment: @vancoder I'm not even sure I should be doing get_template_path. The file only contains HTML and a few variables I have set in the file that calls it. Maybe `include (TEMPLATEPATH . 'includes/my_email_template.php');` is the correct option?

Comment: Does your template file return a string? If you just include it any HTML or `echo`s will just print to the screen rather than get assigned to `$body`. I imagine that will cause some errors with `wp_mail` as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per my comment to your question, I believe the problem is that `include`ing files, whether directly or using `get_template_part` isn't likely to give you a string to pass to `$body` and that is going to cause errors in the code, or at the very least unespected behavior.

I would avoid reading files into memory and just create a function that returns your `$body` content.

```
function get_email_body_wpse_96357() {
    $body = '<p>Hi</p>';
    return $body;
}
```

Then use `$body = get_email_body_wpse_96357();` as needed. An advantage of this method is that you can easily pass parameters to the function if you ever decide to do so. You could also use variables in an included file but it can be messy.

If you don't want to load that function all the time, then put it in a file by itself and include that file only when you need the function.

Answer (score 13):

Here is the sample code for using output buffering. You will be able to access all the variables inside the template which are defined above "include line".

> *WordPress: Include template in the email.*

```
ob_start();
include(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/email-templates/booking-details-template.php');
$email_content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
wp_mail($to_email, "Booking details", $email_content, $headers);
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to manage customize wp_mail by far

Comment: Used this as well to get the default Woocommerce email header & footer on my custom email sending function by replacing the `include` line with a `do_action` of `woocommerce_email_header`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The function `get_template_part()` doesn't return the HTML but echo it (it uses `locate_template()` which loads the file - echo).

You can either turn output buffering on using [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and put the buffer in to your variable or you can use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

On your case I think the best solution is this:

```
$body = file_get_contents(TEMPLATEPATH . 'includes/my_email_template.php');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ItayXD but I now have it working using the answer above

Comment: I saw, the answer above is a far inferior IMO. The  file_get_contents is exactly what you were looking for, and it is far easier to right html file normally than use the above solution. In fact I just can't see how is it any better, I can see only the down side.

Comment: This is cleaner and easier. Much more MVC by having the logic in functions.php and template in its own file.

Comment: How to pass the variables to templates?

Comment: I've seen passing variables done by using str_ireplace as in str_ireplace('[username]',$user_login, $message_template); -- is this ideal/best practice? - From this link: http://www.avtex.com/blog/2012/03/14/creating-dynamic-html-e-mail-templates-in-wordpress/